# Extract block of consecutive alphanumeric characters from a line of text

Tags: php, regex, string, text-extraction

Imagine I have a list of products, such as:

- Branded HGT15K51B item with words to describe it
- Named CDGL-56 product with a description
- Fancy item with TR64GQE350 with added gizmo
- Another branded 106110 110cm sized green item with fan

I am trying to extract the product code only.

This will be a large block of consecutive text. It may contain A-Z 1-9 with _ -. It's always uppercase. It will always end with a space. It has an unknown length. It may be numeric only. It's always the largest consecutive block in the string.

My regex skills are weak, is it possible to extract with a regex? is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: If they always follow the same pattern like this where you have product name followed by id followed by description, then it is possible. But there are so many edge cases that could cause false positives that you likely won't get anything that covers 100%.

Comment: The only distinction is `(?<!\S)[A-Z0-9-]+(?!\S)`

Comment: Is regex not a good fit for this problem?

Comment: It is a good fit. But what is the distinction here `may not contain any A-Z characters` vs `It may contain A-Z 1-9` ?

Comment: There needs to be a more distinct pattern to match all cases like a delimeter or similar. You could also narrow down the rules to not be so generic which will prevent more false positives. Like looking for specific structures, letters numbers letter. Or making sure the model number is of a minimum length like minimum 5 characters would prevent windows 2000 from thinking 2000 is the model number.

Comment: @sln bah thats my typo, let me fix

Comment: You can try this [(?<!\S)\[A-Z0-9-\]+(?!\S)](https://regex101.com/r/zHE8nc/1)

Comment: @sln thanks! that seems to work for my test cases and the other items in the db.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Good call, assuming I used something like https://regex101.com/r/zHE8nc/1 could I set a min of say 5 characters?

Comment: replacing the `+` with `{5,}` would mean 5 or more. You could also find all matches in the string and then just strlen each to find which is longest.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn amazing, thank you!

Comment: @MunimMunna ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

`(?<!\S)[A-Z0-9-]{5,}(?!\S)`

https://regex101.com/r/zHE8nc/2

```
 (?<! \S )        # Whitespace boundary
 [A-Z0-9-]{5,}    # Allowed characters, minimum 5
 (?! \S )         # Whitespace boundary
```

Comment: Setting a lower limit is useful, have modified to use {5,}